# DB issue on MAAS Dashboard page

Tags: maas

When attempting to load the MAAS dashboard page, I get the following error:

```
'relation "maasserver_discovery" does not exist LINE 1: ...","maasserver_discovery"."is_external_dhcp" FROM "maasserve... ^'
```

I've successfully deployed MAAS with the dashboard page when the PostgresDB has been local. I've since moved the DB to an AWS instance and am starting to see these issues.

Answer (score 0):

Asked on the IRC channel. I was attempting to use an AWS RDS PostgreSQL backend which isn't fully supported yet. There seems to be permissions issues when trying to actively update the DB on UI changes. This table should be created every time maas-region starts